# Limit max number for <input> using the value of another <input> component in Angular 2

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have 2  components of type number. The first has validation to only allow numbers between 0 and 20.

The second component is disabled until the first component has a valid number entered.

I want the second to be validated so numbers between 0 and the value of the first input are allowed.

How do I do this?

My **HTML**:

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-label stacked>Number of previous pregnancies *</ion-label>
    <ion-input formControlName="prevPregnancies" type="number" (ionChange)="prevPregChange()"></ion-input>
</ion-item>
<ion-item>
    <ion-label stacked>Number of previous deliveries *</ion-label>
    <ion-input [disabled]="prevPregnanciesValid"  formControlName="prevDeliveries" type="number" max="{{ prevPregnancies }}"></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

Comment: What happens currently? Have you tried an actual binding `[max]="..."`

Comment: Page wouldn't load. No errors in server logs. I actually ended up using the range component, where using min and max worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try:

`<ion-input [disabled]="prevPregnanciesValid"  formControlName="prevDeliveries" type="number" [max]="formGroup.get('prevPregnancies').value"></ion-input>`

Make sure to replace 'formGroup' with the name of your actual form group.